# Flutter Qs : Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

So i want to show my API feedback as a text, here is where i call the api

```
Future <Map<String, dynamic>> SaldoUpdate() async {
    var rawJson =
    await GetSaldoRefresh();
    Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);

    var saldo = map["VALUE"]["SALDO"];
    
    print (saldo);
    return saldo;
  }
```

and heres the API feedback look like

```
flutter: 0.00
```

and i want to show that Value on text widget,

so i use future builder but it shows this error when i try to return the saldo String

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Future SaldoUpdate() async {
 var rawJson = await GetSaldoRefresh();
 var map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
 var saldo = map["VALUE"]["SALDO"];
 print(saldo);
 return saldo;
}
```